# Can Office 2010 Beta 64 bit be installed on a machine with Office 2007?

Tags: 64-bit, microsoft-office, office-2010-beta

When trying to install Office 2010 Beta on a machine with Office 2007, I received an error message saying it was unable to install because Office 2007 is already installed(which of course is not available in a 64 bit edition).

Are there ways around this?

For now, I installed Office 2010 Beta 32 bit version in a virtual machine.

Comment: Yes you can, but only if you have access to the Click-to-Run version of the Beta (available to the participants of the Office 2010 Click-to-Run Beta for Home and Small Business Consumers in Connect). Apart from that Diago's answer is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**

The Shared Components also need to be upgraded to 64Bit. 32Bit Office 2010 does allow it for everything except Outlook.

Answer (score 1):

**You can** ...kinda

I have installed the (32bit) office 2010 beta along side my office 2007 install. I don't know if it can be done with the 64bit version

you need to select 'customize' and choose a different folder to install it in (e.g 'microsoft office 2010' instead of the default 'microsoft office'.

there are a few buts: apparently both versions of outlook cannot co-exist and also each time you run the older/newer version office takes a couple of minutes to re-configure itself.

apart from that it seems to work for me fine

Answer (score 0):

actually you can but it requires some hacking.  if you are running windows 7 with xp mode installed, you can install one version in that virtual machine.  i saw a microsoft rep with this setup a few months ago and it worked just fine.

Comment: Yeah, but that can be said about any program: "just put it in a virtual machine." The OP is asking if they can be installed side-by-side on one machine.